# wordpress issues 404 error and home button doesn't take me to homepage

Tags: wordpress

This is my website [www.jed-media.com](http://www.jed-media.com)

The issue is when i create a post it doesn't go onto my homepage and when i click home button it takes me to [www.jed-media.com/home](http://www.jed-media.com/home) not [www.jed-media.com](http://www.jed-media.com)

So can anyone help me because this is the first time that i am going to create a website and it's the first time using wordpress. also if you could recommend any themes that would be brilliant.

Comment: What version of WP are you using? Is your homepage just a page? or is it your home.php?

Comment: are those pages automaticly apear in the top menu? do you use custom menu? whats your permalink structure currently?

Comment: Joey its the newest version and Sagive i'm not sure i've just started wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've set up a page in the backend to be 'Home' (thus it creates {yoururl}/home)

To update this [create a static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) by going to **Administration > Settings > Reading panel.**  and Set 'Front page displays:' to 'a static page' and choose your page (home)

For the rest of your site I strongly suggest checking out [First Steps With Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/First_Steps_With_WordPress) guide, should help you out a bit.